# Cannot include .cpp and .h files in Visual Studio 2022

Tags: c++, include

I have created a class Dialog and separated it into .cpp (Dialog.cpp) and .h (Dialog.h).
My cpp file looks like this:

```
#include "Dialog.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

namespace Model1
{
    void Dialog::initialize ()
    {
          cout << "initialization";
    }
}
```

And here is my h file:

```
using namespace std;
class Dialog
    {
        public:
            void initialize ();
    };
```

When I debug the code in visual studio 2022 I get this:

```
cannot open source file "Dialog.h"
name followed by '::' must be a class or namespace name
Cannot open include file: 'Dialog.h': No such file or directory ConsoleApplication1 
symbol cannot be defined within namespace 'Model1'  ConsoleApplication1
```

When I changed my header file to

```
using namespace std;
namespace Model1 {
    class Dialog
    {
    public:
        void initialize();
    };
}
```

And now I have these errors:

```
cannot open source file "Dialog.h"
name followed by '::' must be a class or namespace name
Cannot open include file: 'Dialog.h': No such file or directory
```

How can I fix the problem?

Comment: The out-of-class definition for the member function of a class must be in the same namespace in which the containing class is. But the problem with your code is that in the header file you've defined class Dialog in global namespace while you're trying to define the member function `Dialog::initialize()` in Model1 namespace. There are **2 ways of solving this** as explained in my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74583375/12002570) below.

Comment: *"cannot open source file "Dialog.h""* -- Is that in fact the name of your header file? Sure, it is a traditional name for the header for a class named `Dialog`, but your question does not explicitly give its name, only calling it "my h file". Also, on some systems, `Dialog.h` is not the name of `dialog.h` (and on all systems is not the name of `Dialog.hpp`).

Comment: @JaMiT yes, the name of the header file is Dialog.h

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The **problem** is that in the header file you've defined class `Dialog` in *global namespace* while you're trying to define the member function `Dialog::initialize()` in `Model1` namespace.

This will not work because **the out-of-class definition for the member function of a class must be in the same namespace in which the containing class is**.

Thus, to solve this you can either define the class(in the header) in namespace `Model1` or implement the member function(in the source file) in global namespace. Both these methods are shown below:

##### Method 1

Here we define the class in namespace `Model1` in the header and leave the source file *unchanged*.

**dialog.h**

```
namespace Model1   //added this namepspace here
{
class Dialog
    {
        public:
            void initialize ();
    };
}
```

[Working demo 1](https://onlinegdb.com/cOB_7GTma)

---

##### Method 2

Here we define the member function in global namespace in source file and leave the header file *unchanged*.

**dialog.cpp**

```
#include "Dialog.h"
void Dialog::initialize ()
{
      cout << "initialization";
}
```

[Working demo 2](https://onlinegdb.com/XafCnZF02)

Comment: I learned that *the out-of-class definition for the member function of a class must be in the same namespace in which the containing class is.* Beautiful. +1

Comment: Thank you! I have changed my project a little bit (and editted my question too). The problem is I'm working in Visual Studio 2022 and I also get a few errors even after following your advice.

Comment: @JasonLiam I compiled it one more time in Visual Studio and it worked. Thank you! Now I understand that these two files have to be in the same namespace.